# Rename CSV header using command line tools

Tags: linux, unix, sed, csv, awk

Given a CSV file,

```
h1 h2 h3
a  b  c
z  x  b
```

how to rename the first header to `One` and the third header to `Three` using command line tools, namely

```
One h2 Three
a   b  c
z   x  b
```

Comment: If you are familiar with VBScript you can do it easy: read the file, call Replace() - ready!

Comment: Let's not reinvent the wheel here, it is something that is done so many times with solutions in pure BAT, VBS, Powershell.. etc. CSV is a text file so just google for 'file text replace in bat'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/bash-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file

The header should just be the first line in your file, so if you use N = 1, and rewrite the line with the desired headers, so:

```
sed -i '1s/.*/One, h2, Three/' file.csv
```

will do it

Comment: Add that this is a *nix solution ;)

Comment: what is a nix solution?

Comment: oh right, I get it now... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like

Comment: This is incorrect, as the CSV header can span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Sed has the "change" command `c` to replace the whole current line:

```
sed -i '1c\One h2 Three' file.csv
```

This works with GNU sed. Others seds might need the text to be entered on a separate line:

```
sed -i '1c\
One h2 Three' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Line-based solutions (such as `sed`-based) won't work for multiline csv headers.

So you need something to understand csv format.

For example with `csvtool` (ocaml):

```sh
echo 'My,New,Header'      > output.csv
csvtool drop 1 input.csv >> output.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

The below command should work

```
sed -i '1s/h1/One/;1s/h3/Three/;' file.csv
```

`-i` edits the file in place.

`1` executes the operation in the first line.

`s/h1/One/` substitutes h1 with One.

Comment: Welcome on the SU! What it does? And how?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.